# Как поменять background-color элемента select при клике на option?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Хочу изменить цвет элемента.
Есть элемент список но в качестве значений этого элемента я использую цвет `background-color`.

```
<select style="background-color: red;" class="select new">
  <option style="background-color: green;" value="green"></option>
  <option style="background-color: yellow;" value="yellow"></option>
  <option style="background-color: blue;" value="blue"></option>
  <option style="background-color: red;" value="red"></option>
</select>
```

Пробовал через `jQuery`:

```
$(option).click(funсtion(){ $(select).style("background-color:red;") });
```

Но так не получается.
Как при клике на элемент `option` менять цвет элемента `select`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При самом клике на `option` никак, надо использовать ивент `change`, когда меняется значение селекта :

Вариант на чистом `JavaScript` :

```js
var select = document.querySelector('.select.new');
select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  select.style.backgroundColor = select.value
});
```

```html
<select style="background-color: red;" class="select new">
  <option style="background-color: green;" value="green">green</option>
  <option style="background-color: yellow;" value="yellow">yellow</option>
  <option style="background-color: blue;" value="blue">blue</option>
  <option style="background-color: red;" value="red">red</option>
</select>
```

Вариант на `JQuery` :

```js
var select = $('.select.new');
select.on('change', function() {
  select.css('background-color', select.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select style="background-color: red;" class="select new">
  <option style="background-color: green;" value="green">green</option>
  <option style="background-color: yellow;" value="yellow">yellow</option>
  <option style="background-color: blue;" value="blue">blue</option>
  <option style="background-color: red;" value="red">red</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, именно такое поведение мне и нужно было. Но вот странность, это работает только на одном элементе, второй почему-то не хочет переключаться.

Все сделал по аналогии, создаю новый select с классом add у этого элемента такой скрипт:
$('select.add').on('change', function() {$('.select.add').css('background-color', $('.select.add').val());})
 
мой пример можно глянуть тут: https://github.com/SerheosMorello/ToDoList

Comment: @SerheosMorello вы добавляете функцию на чейндж селекта по загрузке страницы, а потом добавляете новый селект, у которого етой функции нету, так как добавлялась она раньше, можно селекту прописать `onchange`, или использовать делегирование событий

Comment: Ну если я Вас правильно понял то:
window.onchange = function(){
  $('select.add').on('change', function() {$('.select.add').css('background-color', $('.select.add').val());})
}
метод у элемента появился после клика, но только он не отрабатывает
https://www.dropbox.com/s/oiu3zvupsc1005a/Capture2.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Даже пробовал добавить:

function changetype(){
$('select.add').on('change', function() {$('.select.add').css('background-color', $('.select.add').val());})
}

select.addEventListener("change", changetype, false); 

при создании нового элемента, но почему-то не срабатывает.

Comment: @SerheosMorello сделайте так :
`$(document).on('change', 'select.add',  function() {$('.select.add').css('background-color', $('.select.add').val());})`

Comment: и так тоже не помогает.
просто магия какая-то(

Comment: @SerheosMorello у вас в создании нового селекта `option1.value ="#fd7777;";` там точка с запятой после цвета не нужна, сделайте так : `option1.value ="#fd7777";`